# Excel write an array of values directly in the formula

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

I have this (working) formula in Excel:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2019,1,1),DATE(2019,12,31))
```

Basing on the formula description I can add a list of dates to be excluded from the computation. I would like to define this directly in the formula like this (still working as expected)

```
=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2019,1,1),DATE(2019,12,31),{"03-04-2019","06-04-2019"})
```

As you can see the dates in the list are strings "03-04-2019" and "06-04-2019", I want to use DATE instead.
If I try to convert the first string and add it as a value to the formula like this

```
=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2019,1,1),DATE(2019,12,31),DATE(2019,4,3))
```

It still works as expected. 
Now I would like to add the second date to the exclusion list like this:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2019,1,1),DATE(2019,12,31),{DATE(2019,4,3),DATE(2019,4,4)})
```

But it doesn't work. (If you compare to the second example above you can see that it is the same formula I just changed the Strings with the DATE). 
What's wrong? How can I solve this WITHOUT putting the list of DATE in the sheet and reference to them?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Totorial](https://www.keynotesupport.com/excel-functions/networkdays-function.shtml), you can refer multiple dates for Holidays field with 3 ways:

1- using an array of dates , inside two brackets {}, with dates in format of [serial numbers of dates](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5293-excel-date-to-serial-number.html)

2- using cell references; which you don't want to use

3- using an array of text dates, as you already used

Comment: The problem is the text dates that are interpreted differently by different excel configurations. In both 1 and 3 I have this constraint. I would like to write dates in a unequivocal way like DATE(year,month,day)